# Style Mapped Material-UI Icons with the Same Styles (React)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, icons

Without adding a className or style tag to each object with a material-ui icon element, what's the best way to style each icon if each icon has the same style?

```js
const btns = [
  { name: "test1", icon: <Icon1 />, link: "test1" },
  { name: "test2", icon: <Icon2 />, link: "test2" },
  {
    name: "test3",
    icon: <Icon3 />,
    link: "test3",
  },
  { name: "test4", icon: <Icon4 />, link: "test4" },
  { name: "test5", icon: <Icon5 />, link: "test5" },
  { name: "test6", icon: <Icon6 />, link: "test6" },
  { name: "test7", icon: <Icon7 />, link: "test7" },
  { name: "test8", icon: <Icon8 /> },
];

const LeftNav = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className="leftNavContainerStyle">
      {btns.map((btn) => {
        return (
          <Button className={classes.navBtnContainer} color="primary">
            {btn.icon} //add the same style to each icon.
            {btn.name}
          </Button>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default LeftNav;
```

Ive tried changing each icon key to: `{ name: "test1", icon: Icon1, link: "test1" }`, and then changing `btn.icon` to `<btn.icon/>` and adding a style like `<btn.icon style={styles}/>`, but this errors out.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out,

```js
import { SvgIcon } from "@material-ui/core"; //import SvgIcon


const btns = [
  { name: "test1", icon: Icon1, link: "test1" },//remove tags from icon components
  { name: "test2", icon: Icon2, link: "test2" },
  {
    name: "test3",
    icon: Icon3,
    link: "test3",
  },
  { name: "test4", icon: Icon4, link: "test4" },
  { name: "test5", icon: Icon5, link: "test5" },
  { name: "test6", icon: Icon6, link: "test6" },
  { name: "test7", icon: Icon7, link: "test7" },
  { name: "test8", icon: Icon8 },
];

const LeftNav = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className="leftNavContainerStyle">
      {btns.map((btn) => {
        return (
          <Button className={classes.navBtnContainer} color="primary"> //use the component from SvgIcon
            <SvgIcon component={btn.icon} className="whateverclassyouwant" /> 
            {btn.name}
          </Button>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default LeftNav;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the React.cloneElement function and then just pass in the style when it gets cloned. So something like this

```js
{btns.map((btn) => {
    return (
        <Button className={classes.navBtnContainer} color="primary">
            {React.cloneElement(btn.icon, {
                // pass in any new props into this object
                className={...}
            })}
            {btn.name}
        </Button>
    );
})}
```